# Printf in keil for stm32f4-eval2 board

Tags: c++, printf, stm32, keil

Is there c++ or c code anywhere that will help me use printf in keil uvision 5 for the stm32f4-eval2 board?  I  know you have to retarget the uarts and usarts but I have not been able to do this without errors even with help from the sites I have found online.

I would like to be able to use the debug printf viewer.

I tried the following link but it did not work: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkpro/ulinkpro_trace_itm_viewer.htm

Comment: there are some retarget.c and serial.c files online but none of those work

Answer (score 2):

You are not very specific if you want to print via UART or if you want to print via ITM debug channel. For ITM it is pretty simple. Create a file with the following content and make sure SWO trace is enabled on your debug connection:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* Replace next line: Include the device system header file here */
#error "device include file missing"
/* e.g.: #include "STM32F4xx.h" */

#pragma import(__use_no_semihosting_swi)

volatile int ITM_RxBuffer = ITM_RXBUFFER_EMPTY;  /*  CMSIS Debug Input        */

int fputc(int c, FILE *f) {
  return (ITM_SendChar(c));
}

int fgetc(FILE *f) {
  while (ITM_CheckChar() != 1) __NOP();
  return (ITM_ReceiveChar());
}
```

Make sure you tick the "Use MicroLib" option in Options for Target->Target

Comment: ITM.cpp(10): error:  #734: function "fputc(int, std::FILE *)" conflicts with using-declaration of function "std::fputc(int, std::FILE *) C"

Comment: The library retargetting should be done in C. You are trying to compile that as C++. Just rename the file to .c.

Comment: Not sure why I did that. Now I am getting an error that "symbol fputc multiply defined (by itm.o and k_log.o)"

Comment: is k_log.c part of your project? It seems to do retargetting already.