# PRINTF in Keil uvision5

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, keil

I am working for the first time with the STM32 Nucleo L476RG board with the X-Nucleo IDB05A1 Expansion board for developing Bluetooth Low Energy Applications.
I will develop with Keil uvision5. In uvision5 I could succesfully built the SensorDemo example from the STM32CubeExpansion package, loaded the code to the flash memory of the board and started a debug session/run the code.

In that code example are a lot of PRINTF statements used. But where can I see the output of those?

I tried things like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755266/printf-in-keil-mcb4300-using-j-link) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605244/printf-in-keil-for-stm32f4-eval2-board) but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me out or has an easier solution?

Or would there be an easier or better environment for developping with STM32 bluetooth low energy boards?

Thanks in Adavance!

Comment: Clarify "but it didn't work" to the point where it might actually form a specific answerable question. In the absence of that, I'm going to guess you mean that enabling the retargeting feature caused your board to turn into a giraffe, and frankly I'm flabbergasted as to how _that_ could have happened...

Comment: That PRINTF statements are much useful when using SensorDemo example, I have used retargeting functionality of MDK-ARM ( http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm ) to redirect PRINTF output to UART2 of STM32L053 Nucleo Board. For that you need to enable UART2 (Which preferred because UART2 will be available as virtual Com Port when Nucleo Board is connected.). I found this technique from basic LED blink+Printf example in STM32 Code Snippets.